# Button not enabled even after providing CommandParameter in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icommand

I created a button whose commandparameter is set and command using a class that implements ICommand interface. But my button is disabled. Why is that? I got this code from here: [ICommand is like a chocolate cake](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/03/20/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake.aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="ICommand_Implementation_CSharp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ICommand_Implementation_CSharp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>      
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:HelloWorldCommand x:Key="hwc"  />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Command="{StaticResource hwc}" CommandParameter="Hello" 
                Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,138,0,0" 
                Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and my class is

```
class HelloWorldCommand:ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter != null;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is very-very simple implementation of `ICommand`.

As @JleruOHeP says, partially problem can be solved by swapping setters of `Command` and `CommandParameter`. But this is ugly way, because you have to remember the sequence every time.

More correct way is to tell `CommandManager` to re-query states of command:

```
public class HelloWorldCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter != null;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now the sequence of setters is indifferent.
To understand how `CommandManager` works, you can read [this](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/) nice article from Josh Smith.

Comment: +1 I`ve just started to type complex explanation, but you was faster :)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, look at this post: http://waxtadpole.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/wpf-mvvm-in-vb-net-delegating-event-subscriptions-for-routedcommand-or-any-icommand-in-the-viewmodel/

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer - switch places of Command and Command parameter:

```
<Button CommandParameter="Hello" Command="{StaticResource hwc}" .../>
```

But better one is given by @Dennis

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the `CommandParameter` type that was causing the issue. My button was simply bound like this:

```
<Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}" CommandParameter="False" />
```

The underlying `NewCommand` is a `RelayCommand<bool>`. Somehow XAML was not able to translate `False` to bool. (Note that it does work for many built-in types and properties; maybe some `TypeConverter` or something at action there).

Solution was to simply spoon-feed XAML about the real underlying type of `CommandParameter`, like this:

```
<Button Content="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <sys:Boolean>
          False
        </sys:Boolean>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

You have to import `sys` namespace at the top of your XAML file, like this:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Hope this helps someone down the road.