# Do order of code in XAML effect its build relevance in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I asked a question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104274/button-not-enabled-even-after-providing-commandparameter-in-wpf) regarding

```
<Button Command="{StaticResource hwc}" CommandParameter="Hello" ...
```

in which to overcome my problem i was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104379/1011959) to switch the place of these two attributes i.e. `CommandParameter` should come first and Command` later. This way

```
<Button CommandParameter="Hello" Command="{StaticResource hwc}" ...
```

No doubt, this thing worked. But left a few questions in my mind.

1. Do the order of attributes matter?
2. Does this same principle apply to styles also. My seniors at job say styles should be written/defined in a file before they are used

I have a button designed

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FooStyle}" ....
```

and the style is defined way down below after this button is declared

```
<Style x:Key="FooStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Path}" ...
```

Will this style be applied to that button even though it is declared after button is declared?

In code behind we cannot use a variable before its declaration, so does the same apply to XAML code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed you need to define your Style above its usage if you are referring to it using `StaticResource` but in case you are referring it as a `DynamicResource`, the order does not matter. It gets resolved at run time.

```
<Button Style={DynamicResource FooStyle}...
```

Refer to this link for detailed description for the difference [StaticResource vs DynamicResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)